# Unable to route to website in home network

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have a home network running my own webserver. Everything worked fine until I updated my ISP to fiber optic. With this new connection came a new modem. The new router is a ActionTec V1000. I found out early on that while I could hit my site externally, I couldn't access it internally because it has NAT loopback disabled. The fiber optic also allows a TV service so I can't simply swap out the router as the TV service has some specific requirements itself.

The suggested solution was for me to get a second router, place it in the DMZ of the ActionTec and point all port 80 calls to that router. I purchased and installed an ASUS RT-66nu router. I attached the WAN port of the router to a LAN port on the ActionTec. I configured the ActionTec to put the Asus into the DMZ. I also forwarded the port 80 calls (and 443) to the Asus inside the DMZ.

Now I know the port forwarding is working, because when I test it from an external site the port shows open. If I disable port forwarding on the ASUS (which is pointed to my web server on port 80), the connection shows unavailable. I know the site is up because I can get to it on the local host of the server. I figure I have some sort of missing setting on my network because it probably doesn't know how to get from my web server through the ASUS -> ActionTec and out.

I would appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you access your webserver externally (e.g. by entering your public IP in a web browser)?

If your modem is configured to use a network (e.g. `192.168.1.0`) and your router is configured to use a different network (e.g. `192.168.0.0`) those networks may not be able to properly talk to each other.  When you run `ipconfig /all` from a computer connected to the ASUS router, and `ipconfig /all` from a computer connected to the Modem directly, what is the IP address and default gateway of your connection?

Comment: That's probably the problem.  The routers are completely different IPs.  Can I maintain this, but still let them see each other?  I am sure there is a way to let the ASUS see the ActionTec network.

Comment: What's the IP of your modem set to?